# Converting Qt compliant C++ to ui XML(QtDesigner) format:

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, qt-designer

I have C++ widget code that was generated by QtDesigner (Qt open source v 4.7.3, using the Form->View Code menu in QtDesigner).

I have modified that code in a manner that is entirely Qt compliant - just hand coded a few more signals, slots and wigdets based on the patterns of the generated code - code runs perfectly when built with Code::Blocks.

Now I'd like to convert my modified C++ source back into the ui XML format that QtDesigner uses. I'm looking for a quick way of doing that (Win7-32 platform).

Any suggestions?

TIA

Comment: I have never met even hard vay to do that. Who would write c++ analyzer to generate XML ?

Comment: Qt does XML->C++ - why not go both ways? You can do it with 'two way tools' such as  Delphi - write text, get back code, write code, get back text. Then you can modify your previously generated code by hand or in designer. I often do this with Delphi.

Comment: I've never heard of that either. Rule of thumb: never modify generated code.

Comment: Qt has an XML format that it parses to generate code - you should be able to go the other way if your C++ code is Qt compliant. The alternative is to generate new C++ code in the designer and then merge with your mods - which would you prefer? Perhaps modularization is needed - the Qt generated C++ code tends to be monolithic.

Comment: The question is, why? For signals and slots, QtDesigner can do it really easily and in a maintainable (and clean) way. For the additional widgets, simply copy/paste the code on the original .cpp implementation (not the moc_*.cpp one). But if you _want_ to see them nice and pretty on QtDesigner you will need to do the work from 0 on designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The c++ is a really complex language to parse, so it would be really hard / long / expensive to develop such a tool I guess.

The general rule is to never modify generated code ( in your case the code is generated by Qt designer)

You can

- Subclass the generated class and put your modifications in the sub class
- Code all your interfaces by yourself from scratch.
- If you think Qt designer lack features you can request them or submit patches to Qt. But I don't think Qt intend to extend that, since QML has become the new way to go with interfaces.

The best option for you is probably the first.

Comment: "The best option for you is probably the first." - could be, as per my comment above - inherit from new extensions from the generated widgets so they don't get trashed by the designer - my other option, which might be the best for me, is to just do a diff/merge. The slots/signals support in QtDesigner seems to be limited which is why I've been doing my own mods on the generated code

Answer (score 0):

A software introspection tool, [GammaRay](https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay), can save widgets from a running Qt application to `.ui` files (since 2012, I believe). Tested on Qt 5.12 - layout is perfectly correct, but no signals, no object names, though it gives a good starting point in restoring objects' hierarchy and its properties.

All kudos to [Marc Mutz - mmutz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134841/marc-mutz-mmutz) and [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9214657/1104612).