# Qt object/class to Qt ui file

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

This may seem like a very strange question but is it possible to generate a Qt Designer form (`.ui`) from a Qt object, say something that inherits `QWidget`?

My plan is to build a simple dynamic form in code as the user picks what stuff they want e.g fields, type of control and then dump out a `.ui` file so that they can tweak the layout if needed after.

The code will then use the `QUiLoader` class to reload the `ui` file and show the modified or not `ui` file.

Comment: I would love to have that facility, to convert masses of pre-Qt-Designer hand-crafted widget creation code to .ui files. I asked about it ages ago - of a Qt developer, I think - and the answer then was 'no'. I'd love to know if it's since become possible.

Comment: This topic was discussed in March 2011 in a [Qt Centre forum post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/39911-How-to-create-.ui-file-from-hand-written-header-and-source-files-only.). One person said they could do the conversion, for a fee, but no available tool was mentioned.

Comment: @Clare Macrae: I perceive the Qt Centre forum post as an attempt to directly parse source codes so as to yield an .ui file (static) whereas the OP stressed the dynamic of building a simple form through user interaction and persist the outcome as an .ui file (a form designer?).

Comment: @menjaraz Yes, I'm sure you're right.

Answer (score 3):

The Qt-Introspection tool [GammaRay](https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay) can save dialogs from the AUI (Application Under Inspection) to `.ui` files in its latest version, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Since QWidget inherits from QObject, it gets all of the dynamic property inspection QObject provides. QObjects (and QWidgets) also naturally arrange themselves into trees (see QObject::parent and QObject::children). By following the tree of widgets, and getting the properties of each one, you can generate an xml .ui file containing the basic info about each control.

Working out the signal/slot connections from a pre-established form might be a bit more tricky, since there doesn't seem to be any way to get information on them besides QObject::dumpObjectInfo but for the program you describe in your question it's easy enough to keep track of them some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Let my just clarify something, Qt Designer has a WYSIWYG user interface that creates a Qt Designer form in xml format, which is then converted to C++ code at compile time. And you're asking if one can do this backwards?

Yes, i do think it is possible, since Qt Designer Forms are just xml anyway. You can make an application that accepts C++ code, specifically the code used for the complete declaration of a class, then translate the PROPERTIES of the class into their corresponding xml code. This would involve a lot of work, in which at that point, i personally don't see the point anymore.

edit: this project would require you to reverse engineer Qt Designer. but yes, it is very possible.

Answer (score -1):

not that way. As you remember, UI-file is the source code for generating appropriate .cpp-code at compilet-me. Gui-loader is a part of point-to-implementation pattern, which helps to reduce amount of compile-time.

Comment: A .ui file is just xml describing a widget hierarchy.

Comment: Given that the question relates to loading forms dynamically with UiLoader, their role here is as an external data file which is parsed to create matching controls at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

You could also embedd Qt Designer into your own code using the designer module. You need to add CONFIG += designer to your .pro file.

Please take a look at the designer module here: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtdesigner.html